# Spec$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x(x-t))$ for fixed $t \in \mathbb{C}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes

I know that maxSpec$\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^{2})$ is homeomorphic to the line $\mathbb{A}^{1}$. What can we say about Spec$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x(x-t))$ for fixed complex $t \neq 0$? That is, what does it look like? What happens as $t$ varies?

I suspect not much happens when $t$ is nonzero. When $t \rightarrow 0$ we get Spec$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x^{2})$, for which we know the maximum spectrum of above.

I know that $(x(x-t)) \subset (x)(x-t)$, and so Spec$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x(x-t)) \supset$ Spec$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x)$ $\cup$ Spec$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x-t) = $ Spec$\mathbb{C}[y]$. And since $\mathbb{V}(x(x-t)) = \{(0, z), (t, z) \mid z \in \mathbb{C}\}$, the maximal spectrum contains the ideals $(x, y-z), (x-t, y-z)$. But what else can I say? Is the scheme homeomorphic to the line as well, or something like it?

Comment: For $t \neq 0$ this is isomorphic to $\Bbb A^1 \sqcup \Bbb A^1$ if I am not mistaken, because of the Chinese Reminder theorem.

Comment: @Mike Are you asking this question because you want to understand what it is that makes ${\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C[x,y]/(x^2)$ a "double line"?

Comment: Does this follow from Spec$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x(x-t)) \supset$ Spec$\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x)$ $\cup$ Spec$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x-t)$ ? Do we have equality?

Comment: @Kenny Wong: I suppose that's what I am asking, yes. It is homeomorphic to *the* line $\mathbb{A}^{1}$, but I don't know what Spec$\mathbb{C}[x, y]/(x(x-t))$ looks like for nonzero $t$.

Comment: $y$ is useless here as you can e.g write $k[x,y] \cong k[x] \otimes_k k[y]$. So really, you have to focus on $k[x]/(x^2)$ and $k[x]/(x(x-t))$.

Comment: @Mike Forget about schemes for a moment - let's think about varieties. Are you comfortable with why $V(x(x-t))$ is the union of $V(x)$ and $V(x-t)$?

Comment: @KennyWong I figured since $(x(x-t)) \subset (x)(x-t)$ that we only have inclusion of those closed sets. Now I see that equality holds... So that union of schemes *equals* the original scheme? But I don't know since they are prime ideals and not maximal.

Comment: $(x(x-t)) = (x)(x-t)$

Comment: And don't forget that if $\mathfrak p$ is a **prime** ideal, then $x(x-t) \in \mathfrak p$ is true if and only if either $x \in \mathfrak p$ or $x-t \in \mathfrak p$. Then you can use N.H.'s hint.

Comment: @N.H. Well now I feel silly. I guess this follows from the fact that our ring is commutative.

Comment: Thank you both for the hints. I will close the question.

Comment: You can answer to your own question, it is encouraged on this website as other people in future might be interested by the answer.

Comment: I upvoted. As a last remark, notice that as Kenny Wong said, when $t = 0$, really you will have still a "double line", but again the $y$ coordinate is useless. If you focus on $k[x]$, $Spec(k[x]/(x,x-t))$ will be two points but $Spec(k[x]/(x^2))$ will be a "fat point". It is the beginning of the theory of Hilbert scheme. For example, you can try to compute it tangent space which has dimension 1 even if it's a point !

Comment: @N.H. Ah, yes. So since the only primes containing $(x)$ or $(x-t)$ are these ideals themselves, $Spec k[x]/(x(x-t))$ is a two-point set. But since the only prime containing $(x^{2})$ is $(x)$ (I think?), the scheme $Spec k[x]/(x^{2})$ is a one-point set, and that point is dense in the spectrum. Cool!

Comment: Yes ! Its function ring is $k \oplus k\{\varepsilon \}$ where $\varepsilon^2 = 0$, you can imagine $\epsilon$ as a little vector which want to deform the point, but it's a very small quantity so $\varepsilon^2 = 0$, this is the explanation Grothendieck gaves to biologist for explain what a scheme is !

Answer (score 2):

Because $V(x(x-t)) = V(x) \cup V(x-t)$, we have the equality

$$\text{Spec}\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(x(x-t))} = \text{Spec}\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(x)} \cup \text{Spec}\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{(x-t)} \\
= \text{Spec} \mathbb{C}[u] \cup \text{Spec} \mathbb{C}[v] \\
= \mathbb{A}^{1} \coprod \mathbb{A}^{1}.$$

This holds for any choice of $t \in \mathbb{C}$. But when $t=0$, Spec$\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^{2}) = \{(x)\}$, and so the point $(x)$ is dense.